# Virtual PC with Multi Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have recently intalled Virtual PC and was wondering if it possible to make use of both of my monitors with it. I have managed to get a pseudo multi screen effect by connecting using Remote Desktop connection, but this isn't really what i wanted.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch to the free [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) it has full multi monitor support.